# How do I add a custom icon to the macOS menu bar?

Tags: macos, applescript, high-sierra, software

I’ve been looking and the only thing I can find is how to add ones that already exist. Say I want to add a picture of the pog face, And when I click it it says ok. Is there any software to help me do that, or do I need to code my own AppleScript by myself? (Also I’m on high Sierra.)

Comment: You will need to code your own app to do that, from scratch. Are you sure it's that important?

Comment: I just really want a custom icon on the menu bar, so I won’t mind coding it from scratch, as long as someone gives me through it.

Comment: How much experience do you have with coding apps from scratch?

Comment: So, is what your are wanting is to have an icon of a _pog emote_ show on the **menu bar** and when you click it is "says ok"? What exactly do you mean by "says ok"? When you click it you see literally the word "ok" or it speaks the word or what? How about a **Quit** _command_ too?

Comment: I was just using that as an example, what I meant by says ok is when you click on the face, a bar drops down like if you clicked the keyboard menu icon and it showed all of your keyboards, I want the ok to appear in a list. (Did that make sense?)

Comment: Also yes a quit command would be nice too.

Comment: Then the linked duplicate will get you started.  Also, as you were not completely clear in your question, please take the time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), so the next question you post is clear and concise.